# pyqt, How to Use sectionClicked with lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to use pyqt.

When using 'sectionClicked.connect', (Like below case)
I can use the default(?) parameter(index) that sectionClicked pass to me.

```
self.horizontalHeader = self.table.horizontalHeader()
self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.HeaderClicked)

def HeaderClicked(index):
  ~~~
```

In this case, I want to add arguments at def HeaderClicked.

Like below

```
self.horizontalHeader = self.table.horizontalHeader()
self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(lambda : self.HeaderClicked(foo, bar))

def HeaderClicked(index, foo, bar):
  ~~~
```

But Like this, I can't use parameter that sectionClicked pass to me.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide parameters to a lambda expression so you could do something like this

```
self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(lambda index: self.HeaderClicked(index, foo, bar))

def HeaderClicked(index, foo, bar):
    ...
```

Another option would be to use `functools.partial` instead of a lambda expression, i.e.

```
from functools import partial

self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(partial(HeaderClicked, foo=foo, bar=bar))
```